# Graphic output sensor data

Tags: python, sensor, gui

I have some experience with Arduino but never used Raspberry Pi.

I'm looking for the best way to show my sensors data via RPi.
What I would want to do is:

Arduino to read sensor data and send it to RPi via serial.

RPi to get the data, process, and show it in a TV/Monitor.

I have some idea of all the steps but the last, and I wonder how would be the best way to show the data in the RPi?

I mean, I know I can show it in the console, but I would want to do some basic interface. Colors, font sizes, but not many more.

Which could be the best way to make this?

I'm thinking in a Python program to read the Arduino/Serial data, and show it, but I don't know which library could I use.

The languages I have some experience with are Python, C#, and maybe Javascript.

Would be some of this a good choice?

Comment: Any of those are a good choice. The best method is to install a webserver, like nginx, create html files, or install the php CGI server, and use PHP to execute commands and send them to the browser usign AJAX. I think Python has a webserver too where you can do similar things. Essentially, you need to learn more about creating webpages, jQuery and jQuery plugins and AJAX.

Comment: Consider Tkinter for the screen drawing part.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want that output on the screen.

In the terminal / console / CLI: try [NCurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) (for python [module_curses](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-curses.html)) or [Bash colors](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/colorizing.html) (also available inside [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python))
In the X / windows environment / GUI: try [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/) (with [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/tutorial.html))
In a browser using PHP: try the [PHP GD functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) (for example [imagefillarc()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilledarc.php)) inside [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/)
In a browser using Python: try [PyChart](http://home.gna.org/pychart/), [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/index.htm) or [GD module](http://newcenturycomputers.net/projects/gdmodule.html) (same engine as php) through [Apache](http://modpython.org/) or a [Python simple HTTP server](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html)

If I had to make this I probably go with a browser option, so I can view it from any device available (including the one hosting it all)

Answer (score 0):

You should use PySerial to communicate with your sensor.

You can save the data with a timestamp in a csv file, every second or whatever speed you want.

From inside the python program call GNUplot to generate a png file of the data every 10 seconds and then use a picture viewer, eog, to show the png file on the screen.

You should put the csv file in /dev/shm, which is essentially a ramdisk, for fast access and no sdcard wearout.

If you installed a webserver, you can put a link in index.html to the plotted png and voila, you can access it from anywhere.

The plots of GNUplot are good and only a few kb what result in a very fast webpage.